# How to retrieve last character of string?

Tags: ampscript

I am trying to find something similar to JAvascripts charAt() to get the last character of a String. I am trying using indexof and I just can't. I get the first value returned. Thus, I tried doing it with a loop but I cannot manipulate the looping variables. :(

How could I do something like:

```
SET @char = lastIndexOf(@myString, @whatIamlookingfor) 
OR
SET @char = charAt(@myString, Length(@myString))
```

Please help!!

Comment: Search is your friend.....You would have had the answer an hour ago

Comment: didn't find it. bitter answer as always in stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

An AmpScript function named substring exists...

Now I know nothing about Exacttarget so this come from a simple search and review of the documentation:

```
@myString = 'abcdef';

%%=Substring(@myString,Length(@myString)-1,1)=%%
```

Comment: thank you. I figured it out. it was actually very easy. I was blocked. I used SET @char = lastIndexOf(Length(@myString),  Length(@myString))